# Regex: Getting content from URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to get "`the-game`" using regex from URLs like

- `http://www.somesite.com.domain.webdev.domain.com/en/the-game/another-one/another-one/another-one/`
- `http://www.somesite.com.domain.webdev.domain.com/en/the-game/another-one/another-one/`
- `http://www.somesite.com.domain.webdev.domain.com/en/the-game/another-one/`

Comment: want to use it here http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/modifiers/regex-replace.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var myregexp = /^(?:[^\/]*\/){4}([^\/]+)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

matches whatever lies between the fourth and fifth slash and stores the result in the variable `result`.

Comment: cute... I was thinking that, but I didn't write it as an answer

Comment: Reading from left side I am just looking for whatever text between 4th and 5th slash (/).

Comment: Ah, you beat me on the update!  Amazing how far a little clarification of requirements goes :)

Answer (score 1):

What parts of the URL could vary and what parts are constant?  The following regex will always match whatever is in the slashes following "/en/" - `the-game` in your example.

```
(?<=/en/).*?(?=/)
```

This one will match the contents of the 2nd set of slashes of any URL containing "webdev", assuming the first set of slashes contains a 2 or 3 character language code.

```
(?<=.*?webdev.*?/.{2,3}/).*?(?=/)
```

Hopefully you can tweak these examples to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Reading from left side I am just looking for whatever text between 4th and 5th slash (/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use some kind of url parsing library rather than resorting to using regex.

In python:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
url = urlparse('http://www.somesite.com.domain.webdev.domain.com/en/the-game/another-one/another-one/another-one/')
print url.path
```

Which would yield:

```
/en/the-game/another-one/another-one/another-one/
```

From there, you can do simple things like stripping `/en/` from the beginning of the path.  Otherwise, you're bound to do something wrong with a regular expression.  Don't reinvent the wheel!